# Sum input values and skip one of them jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, input, html-table, sum

I have form which is making sum of numbers but I want that middle input to be skipped by jQuery for summing. Please help with this  I'm posting code here. It surely must be the input tag because it sends data to PHP. I spent so much time to figure this out, but I can't  see the problem.

**jQuery**

```
    var total;
    $("input.amount").keyup(function() {
        total = 0;
        $(this).parents("table").find("input.amount").each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        }).end().find("span.total").html(total);
    });
```

**HTML**

```
  <form class="calc">
    Form 1
    <br />
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Amount 1
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="amount" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Amount 2
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="amount" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Amount 3
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="amount" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Total Amount
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="total">0</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Middle input? Unfortunately we cannot read your mind. Can you please provide us more specific details?

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to skip `Amount 2` field to be added to the sum? If you mean that you can just change the input's class. You are matching elements by `input.amount` so if Amount 2 input doesn't have `amount` class it wont be catched by jQuery.

Comment: Remove `class="amount"` in Amount 2 text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the HTML markup to give the input you wish to ignore a new class or [data-*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) attribute.

```
<input class="amount ignored" type="text" />
```

Then check for the class in your `.each()` loop:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('ignored'))
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
```

If you go down the data-* route, you could use:

```
<input class="amount" type="text" data-ignored="true" />
```

And check making sure that the data attribute is set:

```
if(!$(this).data('ignored'))
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
```

Comment: it was interesting but can you show me on jsfiddle here is link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3DB6r/)

Comment: @Lasha http://jsfiddle.net/3DB6r/4/ both of the "Amount 2" text boxes are ignored.

Comment: i dont know why but on jsfiddle it is working but on html no... what to do now?? :((

Comment: Have you added the "ignored" class to the inputs you want ignored?

Comment: yes i copied from fiddle to html... included jquery 127 file but with no luck :(((

Comment: yes it does the thing... thank you very much James! and thank you all for your replyes :D

Comment: You'd need to run that loop on `$(document).ready()`. Move the loop into its own function and call that function on ready and on keyup.

Comment: and if someones help it this is jsfiddle what we did here today [http://jsfiddle.net/fXWEU/](http://jsfiddle.net/fXWEU/)